# LINQ query works in design view (debug mode) but not published in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, iis

I have the following LINQ sentence

```
 var MercanciasOperativo = from p in db.PLInformacionVerificacionTrasportes

                join abogado in db.Constancias on p.AbogadoResponsable equals abogado.Id into abogadoGroup
                from abogado in abogadoGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()

                join oficio in db.Oficios on p.NumOrden equals oficio.Expediente into oficioGroup
                from oficio in oficioGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()

                join oficioviejo in db.Oficios0908 on p.NumOrden equals oficioviejo.NumOrden into oficioViejoGroup
                from oficioviejo in oficioViejoGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()

                join objPAD in db.MercanciasPuestoDisposicion on p.NumOrden equals objPAD.NumOficio into objPADGroup
                from objPAD in objPADGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()

                join agencia in db.Agencia on objPAD.Agencia equals agencia.Id into agenciaGroup
                from agencia in agenciaGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()

                join subsede in db.Subsedes on agencia.SubsedeId equals subsede.Id into subsedeGroup
                from subsede in subsedeGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()

                join inicio in db.VTInformacionVerificacionTrasportes on p.NumOrden equals inicio.NumOrden into
                    inicioGroup
                from inicio in inicioGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()

                join conceptoMulta in db.PLConceptoMultas on p.ConceptoMulta equals conceptoMulta.Id into
                    conceptoGroup
                from conceptoMulta in conceptoGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()

                join conceptoMultaRegularizacion in db.PLConceptoMultas on p.ConceptoMultaRegularizacion equals
                    conceptoMultaRegularizacion.Id into conceptoRegularizacionGroup
                from conceptoMultaRegularizacion in conceptoRegularizacionGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()

                join notificacion in db.PLNotificaciones on p.TipoNotificacion equals notificacion.Id into
                    notificacionGroup
                from notificacion in notificacionGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()

                join resolucion in db.PLTipoResolucion on p.TipoResolucion equals resolucion.Id into resolucionGroup
                from resolucion in resolucionGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()

                join ciudad in db.Ciudades on p.Ciudad equals ciudad.Id into ciudadGroup
                from ciudad in ciudadGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()

                let Loc = ciudad.Nombre

                join multaExtra in
                    (from p in db.PLMultasExtra
                        group new {p.NumOrden, p.Monto}

                            by new {p.NumOrden}
                        into grp

                        select new
                        {
                            NumOrden = grp.Key.NumOrden,
                            cantidad = grp.Sum(x => x.Monto)
                        }

                        )
                    on p.NumOrden equals multaExtra.NumOrden into multaExtraGroup
                from multaExtra in multaExtraGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()

                where(oficio.StatusExpedienteN != 3 && oficio.StatusExpedienteN != 4 && oficio.StatusExpedienteN != 2 &&oficio.StatusExpedienteN != 7) && (inicio.HuboEmbargo)

                                      select new
                {
                    p.Id,
                    p.NumOrden,
                    OrdenVieja = oficioviejo.NumOrdenViejo ?? p.NumOrden,
                    FechaEmisionOrden = oficio.FechaOficio,
                    OficioProgramacion = oficio.NumOficio,
                    p.UbicacionArchivoTramite,
                    FechaNotificacionOrden = inicio.FechaNotificacionOrden,
                    FechaLevantamientoActa = inicio.FechaLevantamientoActa,
                    FechaEntregaPAMA = inicio.FechaEntregaPAMA,
                    FechaNotificacionPAMA = inicio.FechaNotificacionActa,
                    p.NumExpedientePAMA,
                    NumExpedientePuestoADisposicion = objPAD.NumExpedientePuestoADisposicion,
                    AbogadoResponsable = abogado.Nombre,
                    p.FechaAsignacion,
                    p.FechaIntegracion,
                    p.Plazo4Meses,
                    IDSelector = oficio.IDSelector,
                    IDSUI = oficio.IDSUI,
                    NombreTenedor = inicio.NombreTenedor,
                    NombreTenedor2 = inicio.NombreTenedor2,
                    ApellidoPaternoTenedor = inicio.ApellidoPaternoTenedor,
                    ApellidoMaternoTenedor = inicio.ApellidoMaternoTenedor,

                    Descripcion = inicio.Descripcion_Final.Substring(0, 1000),
                    p.NombreAquienSeEmite,
                    p.NombreAquienSeEmite2,
                    p.ApellidoPaternoAquienSeEmite,
                    p.ApellidoMaternoAquienSeEmite,
                    p.FechaNacimientoAquienSeEmite,
                    p.Rfc,
                    TieneMedioDeDefensa = db.PLMediosDefensa.Any(x => x.NumOrden == p.NumOrden) ? "Si" : "No",
                    TieneLiberacion = db.PLLiberacion.Any(x => x.NumOrden == p.NumOrden) ? "Si" : "No",
                    TieneAdjudicacion = db.PLAdjudicaciones.Any(x => x.NumOrden == p.NumOrden) ? "Si" : "No",
                    TieneCumplimentacion = db.PLResolucionesComplementarias.Any(x => x.NumOrden == p.NumOrden) ? "Si" : "No",
                    p.Calle,
                    p.NumDomicilio,
                    p.Interior,
                    p.Colonia,
                    Ciudad = ciudad.Nombre,
                    p.CP,
                    p.VAM,
                    p.VAMAproximado,
                    p.VAMResolucionPama,
                    MontoCreditoSinRedondear =
                        p.IGI + p.IGIActualizado + p.IGIRecargos + p.IVA + p.IVARecargos + p.IVAActualizado +
                        p.Multa + p.ValorComercial183_A_LA + p.IEPS + p.IEPSActualizado + p.IEPSRecargos + p.CC +
                        p.CCActualizado + p.CCRecargos + (multaExtra.cantidad ?? 0),
                    p.IGI,
                    p.IGIActualizado,
                    p.IGIRecargos,
                    p.IEPS,
                    p.IEPSActualizado,
                    p.IEPSRecargos,
                    p.IVA,
                    p.IVAActualizado,
                    p.IVARecargos,
                    p.CC,
                    p.CCActualizado,
                    p.CCRecargos,
                    p.Multa,
                    ConceptoMulta = conceptoMulta.ConceptoMulta,
                    p.ValorComercial183_A_LA,
                    multaExtra = multaExtra.cantidad ?? 0,

                    tieneRegularizacion = p.tieneRegularizacion ? "Si" : "No",
                    p.MultaRegularizacion,
                    ConceptoMultaRegularizacion = conceptoMultaRegularizacion.ConceptoMulta,

                    Condonacion = p.Condonacion ? "Autorizada" : "Negada",
                    p.SolicitudCondonacion,
                    p.FechaPresentacion,
                    p.OficioResolucion,
                    p.FechaOficioResolucion,
                    p.NotificacionResolucion,
                    p.OficioNotificacion,
                    TipoNotificacion = notificacion.Nombre,
                    TipoResolucion = resolucion.TipoResolucion,
                    p.Plazo45Dias,
                    tieneAutoCorreccion = p.tieneAutoCorreccion ? "Si" : "No",

                    IdPuestoADisposicion = oficio.idPuestoADisposicion,
                    Subsede = Loc,
                    tieneVerificacion = p.Verificado ? "Si" : "No",

                    p.Modifico
                };
```

I know the query could be expensive but i really need all the fields, the problem is in design mode (while Im in visual studio IDE) I start debbuging and it works fine and relatively fast! , but when I publish it in IIS it shows me the next error:

[image]

And if I try to debug it as the message says:

[image]

Im confused because if exists an error it would occur from the desing mode, right?

The file output is above 1mb size. Could be a IIS configuration ?

Comment: You really should consider using navigation properties instead of joins if possible to make the query easier to read.  Something like `from abogado in p.AbogadoResponsables.DefaultIfEmpty()` could replace your first left join.  Here's a [blog post](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/) about it.

Comment: And you should probably view your stack-trace, which will most likely know where your application failed.

Comment: Thanks  juharr, I definitely will use that replacements,  TGlatzer but in debug mode doesnt show nothing, can i do stack trace in a published web site?

Comment: I think the linq query is actually to short. You need to make it longer.

Comment: What are the details of your exception?